# Godot C# - How to implement double jump

Tags: c#, game-physics, game-development, godot, godot4

I want to implement a double jump mechanic in Godot with C#, but it does not work as expected. Maybe someone sees a problem in my code and could give me a hint! :)

My character jumps one time and then goes straight down, instead of doing a double jump.
Appreciate the help.

```
using Godot;

public partial class Player : CharacterBody2D
{
private float _runSpeed = 750;
private float _jumpSpeed = -1000;
private float _gravity = 2500;
private int _jump_counter = 0;
private int _extra_jumps = 1;


public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
{
    var velocity = Velocity;        
    velocity.X = 0;

    var right = Input.IsActionPressed("move_right");
    var left = Input.IsActionPressed("move_left");
    var jump = Input.IsActionPressed("move_jump");
    
    //TODO -> Implement double jump
    if (jump && _jump_counter < _extra_jumps){
        velocity.Y = _jumpSpeed;
        _jump_counter += 1;
        GD.Print(_jump_counter + " " + _extra_jumps);
    }
    
    if (right){
        velocity.X += _runSpeed;
    }
    
    if (left){
        velocity.X -= _runSpeed;
    }
    
    if (IsOnFloor()){
        _jump_counter = 0;
    }
    
    Velocity = velocity;
    
    var animatedSprite2D = GetNode<AnimatedSprite2D>("Sprite2D");

    if (velocity.Length() > 0)
    {
        velocity = velocity.Normalized() * _runSpeed;
        animatedSprite2D.Play();
    }
    else
    {
        animatedSprite2D.Stop();
    }
    
    if (velocity.X != 0)
    {
        animatedSprite2D.Animation = "walking";
        animatedSprite2D.FlipV = false;
        // See the note below about boolean assignment.
        animatedSprite2D.FlipH = velocity.X < 0;
    }
    
    velocity = Velocity;
    velocity.Y += _gravity * (float)delta;
    Velocity = velocity;
    MoveAndSlide(); 
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is how you're taking in your input. For jumping, it might not really be appropriate to check for all presses of the jump key with`Input.IsActionPressed` but rather check for the *first* press of the jump key with `Input.IsActionJustPressed`. Since `PhysicsProcess` is called very repeatedly in a short amount of time, it's very likely that the player is still holding down the key by the next time it's called, thus resulting in two almost concurrent jumps. This is fine for something like moving left and right, which is expected to be a continuous action but not really for jumping which is supposed to be a discrete action.

```
    var right = Input.IsActionPressed("move_right");
    var left = Input.IsActionPressed("move_left");
    var jump = Input.IsActionJustPressed("move_jump");
```

This should fix the issue.